# STUN logs are not coming in Coturn log file?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn, rfc5766turnserver

I am able to test TURN as well as TURNS and while doing testing these, I can see turn and turns logs in coturn log file.

However when doing testing of **STUN, its logs are not coming in turn server in coturn log file**, Although I am able to test call using STUN and getting slrfx as well in Trickle ICE tool.

coturn github url - https://github.com/coturn/coturn

Comment: I got some of the logs by the turnserver service in the syslogs:
/var/log/syslog
This was with and without overriding "log-file" param in the config..
one might think they have changed the "log-file" param keyword to something else, etc and I didnt find anything in the docs. so yeah you can checkout the syslogs, 

The logs I got were for giving wrong turn server username and password, nothing came up for correct connections.

wait.. you got turn logs?? Are you hosting on aws? Can you help me out if you fixed this already?